# How to import a module in the same directory preferred over those in standard library in Python?

Tags: python, import, module

My directory has the following files:

```
main.py
config.py
parser.py
```

And I want to import both `config` and `parser` from `main.py`.

```
from config import *
from parser import *
```

However, the problem is that while I can import `config.py`, I cannot import `parser.py` because a moudle `parser` already exists in standard library (more specifically, the import works but I cannot access the functions defined there).

It seems that I should import it relatively [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384969/python-how-to-import-a-module-which-has-the-same-name-as-a-subpackage):

```
from . import parser
```

But still, the error occurred: `SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import`.

I also tried `from .parser import *` but still got the same error above.

How can I import `parser.py` properly from `main.py`?

I use Python 3.5.1.

Comment: It is _highly_ unpythonic to have custom modules which you want to import with the same name as standard library packages. The easiest way to solve this is to just rename those files.

Comment: @R.Murray Agree, and I solved it by renaming the file. But sometimes I waste so much time just because I don't remember if the name collides or not, which I desperately want to avoid. In fact I spent 40 minutes before knowing about the `parser` library...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function to import a non-local module and then return it like this:

```
def import_non_local(name, custom_name=None):

    import imp, sys

    custom_name = custom_name or name

    f, pathname, desc = imp.find_module(name, sys.path[1:])
    module = imp.load_module(custom_name, f, pathname, desc)
    f.close()

    return module
```

This can be used to import a non-local module, with a file name which is the same as a standard library module, under the same name as the usual standard library.

```
parser = import_non_local('parser','std_parser')
```

`parser` then references your custom non-local library. The local `parser` library can still be imported under a different name:

```
import parser as parser_local
```

The two modules will then not clash and both libraries can be used.

However, as discussed in the comments, you should *just avoid the situation altogether*. If your non-local module has the same name as a standard library then rename your non-local module. The reason it will not import your non-local module over the standard library module is because of the order of access as taken from [here](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path):

> When a module named `spam` is imported, the interpreter first searches for a built-in module with that name. If not found, it then searches for a file named `spam.py` in a list of directories given by the variable `sys.path`. `sys.path` is initialized from these locations:
>
> - The directory containing the input script (or the current directory    when no file is specified).
> - `PYTHONPATH` (a list of directory names, with the same syntax as the shell variable `PATH`).
> - The installation-dependent default.

Comment: Right, I know about the order of access. That's why I want to know if it is still possible to access the correct module, expressly.

Comment: @Blaszard I'll look in to it, but it really is not necessary.

Comment: @Blaszard There we go, I hope that's satisfactory.